# SlickGrid expand/collapse group issue

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I was working with grouping in slickgrid. When I expand and collapse groups, I see that UI is not rendering properly and some rows are not visible at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/sunder_tiwnar/ywzkgwva/

```
http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-grouping
```

For example, open any link, go to last group, and expand it. Then expand group above it, then expand group above that. Carefully notice that some rows will not be visible. In the first link you can notice that the ninth group will go away.

Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks

Comment: check this : https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/1075